# Add ODBC user DSN using python ctypes.windll.ODBCCP32.SQLConfigDataSource

Tags: python, sql, odbc, dsn

I am trying to add new ODBC data source in python and found this code online which seem to work with python 2 (as other people mentioned but I have not tried) but does not work with python 3 (I am using 3.6).  The code runs without error but did not add new DSN to the system (always return 0).

I searched around and found some people mentioning it might be due to the encode issue, so I have tried to change the attribute part to bytes (nul.join(attrib)) with different encoding but none of them works.

Here is part of the code:

```py
ODBC_ADD_DSN = 1        # Add data source, user DSN only
ODBC_CONFIG_DSN = 2     # Configure (edit) data source
ODBC_REMOVE_DSN = 3     # Remove data source
ODBC_ADD_SYS_DSN = 4    # add a system DSN
ODBC_CONFIG_SYS_DSN = 5 # Configure a system DSN
ODBC_REMOVE_SYS_DSN = 6 # remove a system DSN

def add_dsn(name, driver, **kw):
    nul, attrib = '', []
    kw['DSN'] = name
    for attr, val in kw.items():
        attrib.append('%s=%s' % (attr, val))

    return ctypes.windll.ODBCCP32.SQLConfigDataSource(0, ODBC_ADD_DSN, driver, nul.join(attrib))

#
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print (add_dsn('test', 'SQL Server', server='(local)', description = 'Testing'))
```

Can anyone help on how to resolve this issue or provide a solution to add new ODBC data sources using python. Thanks!

Comment: Same problem here. Need to create ODBC dsn for relog.exe. Function creates nothing.

Answer (score 0):

To connect to SQL server using python 3 , I use the below statement and can get the data without any errors.

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(driver='{SQL Server}', server='YourServer', database='YourDBName',               
               trusted_connection='yes')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
```

then you can use pd.read_sql command to retrieve any data.

```
print(pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM [fruits]",cnxn))
```

Output from Database:

```
  fruiteater       Fruit1  Fruit2       Fruit3 Fruit4       Fruit5  Fruit6
      Aaron       Orange    Pear        Apple   None         None    None
         Bob        Apple  Orange  Blueberries  Peach        Mango  Banana
      Carter         Pear  Orange        Apple   None         None    None
       David  Blueberries    None         None   None         None    None
     Earnest        Mango  Orange         Pear  Apple  Blueberries    None
       Frank  Raspberries    None         None   None         None    None
```